# Launch terminal from keyboard shortcut, run interactive command and exit in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, shortcut-keys

I am trying to perform the following:

1. open a gnome-terminal from keyboard shortcut, say Ctrl+Shift+E.
2. Run a command in the terminal. For concrenetess, the command is `gio open $(fzf)`. The command is interactive and launches external program (such as evince).
3. Once the external program is started, close the terminal without closing the external program.

The command I am interested in for step 2 above is `gio open $(fzf)`: I select a file using the fuzzy finder `fzf`, and then the command `gio open` opens that file with the default program of gnome.

I can do the three steps above one by one:

1. I can bind a keyboard shortcut in the settings to `gnome-terminal`: It opens a terminal as expected.
2. Then I type in the newly opend terminal my command `gio open $(fzf)`: If I select a pdf file from `fzf`, it opens evince with the selected file.
3. I can type Ctrl+D to close the terminal. Doing this does **not** close evince. This is the intended behavior.

and doing these three steps manually works.

**My goal is to automate the above.** It should work as follows. As I type the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shit+E (or any other), a gnome-terminal should open, and the command `gio open $(fzf)` should be run. As soon as the interactive command is done (which opens an external program such as evince), the terminal should close automatically without closing evince.

**What I have tried**.

- Adding a keyboard shortcut with the command `gnome-terminal -- bash -c "gio open $(fzf)"` does not work. Pressing the key combination does nothing.
- If I add the command `gio open $(fzf)$` at the end of my .bashrc, a keyboard shortcut with the command `gnome-terminal` opens the terminal and the command is run. As soon as I select a pdf file, evince is opened with the selected file (yeah!!!). But then, if I hit Ctrl+D, the terminal closes and so does evince (maybe because evince is a subprocess?).
- If I add the command `gio open $(fzf)$ && exit` at the end of my .bashrc, a keyboard shortcut with the command `gnome-terminal` opens the terminal and the command is run, but as soon as I select a file, the terminal closes without opening evince (evince might have started and got closed immediately, I cannot tell).

Note that playing with .bashrc was mostly for testing purposes, I would like to avoid polluting my .bashrc.

Comment: ***Launch terminal from keyboard shortcut,*** what about `ctrl`+`alt`+`t`

Comment: The keyboard shortcut should, with only one keypress, launch terminal and run the interactive command.

Answer (score 0):

> *But then, if I hit Ctrl+D, the terminal closes and so does evince
>   (maybe because evince is a subprocess?)*

Yes, sure, it's subprocess and you should run this process as "detached". After that you can end main process (in your case - terminal).

Here is detailed answer how to run detached processes.

https://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely

As another way you can use the next shortcut:

```
bash -c "some_command" > /dev/null &2>&1
```

In this case terminal window will not be raised at all and you don't need to add anything to your .bashrc file.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help. Actually, when I am in an already opened terminal, the command ``gio open $(fzf)`` opens an external program (such as evince), and if later I close the terminal with Ctrl+D, the external program is NOT closed. The external program is closed only in the situation where the command is run from .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing was bugging me, so I'll answer this old question. I've found that `xdg-open` and `gio open` have trouble with this sort of script, and I've also noticed gnome-terminal has trouble with it. For example, xdg-open can open gedit to edit text files, but not evince to view pdfs. So I use the following script with `xterm -e`. Note that this will leave nohup.out files in your home directory, you can redirect stdout if that bothers you.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$(fzf)"

[ - n "$file" ] || exit 1

end="${file##*.}"

case $end in
  pdf | djvu | ps )
    exec nohup evince "$file"
    ;;
  * )
    exec nohup xdg-open "$file"
    ;;
esac
```